# Subleading term in the central limit theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ be i.i.d. Gaussian random variables of mean zero and variance one.

Then 
$$Z:= \sum_i \frac{X_i Y_i}{\sqrt{n}}$$
is approximately Gaussian with 
$$\mathbf E Z =0, \quad \mathbf E Z^2=1.$$
The central limit theorem implies that 
$$\mathbf E f(Z) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbf R} f(x) e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x  + o(1)$$
for any smooth bounded $f$ as $n\to\infty$. Due to the Berry-Essen theorem the convergence rate should be $n^{-1/2}$.

**Question:** Can the subleading term be identified? I.e. can one get 
$$\mathbf E f(Z) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbf R} f(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x + \frac{F(f)}{\sqrt{n}} + o(n^{-1/2})$$
for some $F(f)$? If yes, does this $F(f)$ depend on the derivative of $f$?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [the Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).

Comment: The integral is missing the Gaussian density inside, no?